# What website can tell me my tzdata timezone?

Tags: web-apps, timezones

I can use sites like timeanddate.com to get detailed information about the timezone of a real-world location. For example https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/san-francisco tells me (amongst other things) that San Francisco, USA is in Pacific Time (UTC-7 / UTC-8).

But it doesn't tell me what [tzdata timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) that city is in. (In this case I know that the answer is `America/Los_Angeles` .)

What website allows me to enter a location or city name, and returns the tzdata timezone for that city? Just a user-interface is required, not an API.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the database itself from here https://timezonedb.com/download in either SQL or CSV format and implement your own UI to access the data.

Or if you already know the longtide and latitude you can use this GUI method https://timezonedb.com/ at the bottom.

Or you may use this website http://timein.org/united-states/san-francisco/

At the notes at the bottom where [*1] is, it shows the tzdata timezone.